# Subset of partitions of a set that meets condition

Tags: set-partition

Given a set of integers $\ S = \{1, 2, ... n\}$ and $R$ the set of all possible partitions of S.
Let's define function $f$ which maps a partition $P \in R$ to a multiset containing the cardinalities of elements of $P$: $f(P)=\{\left\vert{p}\right\vert \mid p \in P\}$.
Let A be the set of all equivalence classes on $R$:  $A_i \in A, [A_i] = \{P \in R \mid f(P) = A_j \}\}$. $\left\vert{A}\right\vert = p(n)$, the [integer partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function).

I'm interested in $ Q \subseteq R $ with the following conditions:
1) $\forall A_i \in A, \exists P \in [A_i], P \in Q$.
2) $\forall Q_j \in Q, \forall A_i \in A$ where $f(Q_j) \ne A_i$,let $f(Q_j) \cap A_i = C$, if $C \ne ∅$ then $\exists Q_k \in [A_i], U \subset Q_j, V \subset Q_k, f(U) = f(V) = C$ and $U = V$

I'll try to summarise it in english: I have the partitions of a set. I divide the partitions into equivalence classes based on the length of the elements of the partition (these are the same as the elements in the integer partition of $n$). I need at least one element from each equivalence class. The other condition is that for any subset of any element of my result, $Q$, if there are other elements of my result(in each different equivalence class) that have a subset with the same cardinality as my subset then at least one of them must be equal to the first subset.

**Example1**:
$ S = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$
$[\{4\}] = \{\{\{1, 2, 3, 4\}\}\}$
$[\{3, 1\}] = \{\{\{1, 2, 3\}, \{4\}\}, \{\{1, 2, 4\}, \{3\}\}, \{\{1, 3, 4\}, \{2\}\}, \{\{2, 3, 4\}, \{1\}\}\}$
$[\{2, 2\}] = \{\{\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4\}\}, \{\{1, 3\}, \{2, 4\}\}, \{\{1, 4\}, \{2, 3\}\}\}$
$[\{2, 1, 1\}] = \{\{\{1, 2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}\}, \{\{2, 3\}, \{1\}, \{4\}\}, \{\{3, 4\}, \{1\}, \{2\}\}, \{\{1, 4\}, \{2\}, \{3\}\}\, \{\{1, 3\}, \{2\}, \{4\}\}\{\{2, 4\}, \{1\}, \{3\}\}\}$
$[\{1,1,1,1\}] = \{\{\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}\}\}$
I need (at least) one element from each category.
For example $Q_1 = \{\{\{1, 2, 3, 4\}\}, \{\{1, 2, 3\}, \{4\}\}, \{\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4\}\}, \{\{1, 4\}, \{2\}, \{3\}\}, \{\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}\}\}$  is not a good subset because
a) $\{\{4\}\} \subset \{\{1, 2, 3\}, \{4\}\}$ and $\{\{4\}\} \not\subset \{\{1, 4\}, \{2\}, \{3\}\}$, but  $\{\{2\}\} \subset \{\{1, 4\}, \{2\}, \{3\}\}$ and $f(\{\{2\}\}) = f(\{\{4\}\}) = \{1\}$
b) $\{\{1, 2\}\} \subset \{\{1,2\}, \{3,4\}\}$ and  $\{\{3, 4\}\} \subset \{\{1,2\}, \{3,4\}\}$ but $\{\{1, 2\}\} \not\subset \{\{1, 4\}, \{2\}, \{3\}\},\{\{3, 4\}\} \not \subset \{\{1, 4\}, \{2\}, \{3\}\}$ even though $|\{1, 2\}| = |\{3, 4\}| = |\{1. 4\}|$

$Q_2 = \{\{\{1, 2, 3, 4\}\}, \{\{1, 2, 3\}, \{4\}\}, \{\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4\}\}, \{\{1, 2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}\}, \{\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}\}\}$  meets the criteria. So it is enough to choose a good partition one from each category for $n=4$.

**Example2**:
$S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$
For $n = 5$, the mininum number of partitions required seems to be 12, here is [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvtxM.png) (out of the 5, I think) possible solutions when $Q$ has 12 elements.

So the **question** is: does this problem have a name that I can search for? How could I find the minimum cardinality of $Q$ and what would be a good algorithm to generate it?

Comment: Your description of $A$ is highly confused. First, you don't even define the equivalence relation it is to be the classes for. Instead we have to figure that out forensically from the rest of your post. Second, you call $A$ the set of equivalence classes, but then treat the elements of $A$ as signatures of the classes instead of the classes themselves.